# Overflow error in simple implementation of linear regression in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I encountered this error while running the code:

ErrorValue += ((m*x + b) - y)**2 RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code? It would be great if helpful suggestions can be made on the correctness of my attempt at linear reg as well as ways to improve my code.

Thank you so much!

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

'''
This is a simple implementation of linear regression on correlation
hours studied by student and the marks they obtained.
'''
def run():

    points = genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")

    # x is hours studied, y is marks obtained.

    # We are applying the function: y = b + mx
    for i in range(len(points)):
        x = points[i][0]
        y = points[i][1]

    N = len(points)
    b = 0
    m = 0
    alpha = 0.001 # alpha is the learning rate
    ErrorThreshold  = 0.003
    NumberOfIterations = 1000 # We cancel the gradient descent after a number of iterations, if it still doesn't reach the threshold we want.

    sum_m = 0
    sum_b = 0

    for i in range(NumberOfIterations):
        while mean_squared_error(x,y,b,m,points) > ErrorThreshold:
            b , m  = gradient_descent(m,b,alpha,x,y,N,points)

def mean_squared_error(x,y,b,m,points):
    ErrorValue = 0
    for i in range(len(points)):
        ErrorValue += ((m*x + b) - y)**2
    return ErrorValue / len(points) 


def gradient_descent(m,b,alpha,N,x,y,points):

    #dealing with summation sign in gradient descent
    sum_m = 0
    sum_b = 0

    for i in range(len(points)):
        x = points[i][0]
        y = points[i][1]
        sum_m += m*x + b - y
        sum_b += m*x + b - y 
        #repeating just for clarification purposes.

    new_b = b - (2/N)*sum_b
    new_m = m - (((2*m)/N))*sum_m

    return new_b, new_m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you see when you trace (print) the intermediate values?  For instance, add a couple of lines to your routine.

```
def mean_squared_error(x,y,b,m,points):
    print("ENTER", x, y, b, m, len(points))
    ErrorValue = 0
    for i in range(len(points)):
        ErrorValue += ((m*x + b) - y)**2
        print("TRACE", i, ErrorValue)
    return ErrorValue / len(points)
```

Also, I'm not sure you have your computation correct; I think that you may want

```
        ErrorValue += ((m*x[i] + b) - y[i])**2
```

At the moment, you're multiplying entire vectors, not just scalars, but you're doing it `len(points)` times.

Finally, would it be easier to use `len(x)` and not pass in `points` at all?  You're not using `points` other than for the length.

Comment: When using csv data for machine learning data, it is common to operate on points (where x and y are nested lists), or split them up into x,y variables? Whats the convention for data structures used for data in machine learning? Also, I really appreciate you taking the time to look over my code, thank you

Comment: It's common to handle your data in the largest clumps convenient to code and read: use matrix operations instead of vectors, vectors instead of points, points instead of coordinates.  You *should* be able to get `ErrorValue` as a single command, the sum of an equation mapped on vector elements.